# Salvaged LED Strip

Tags: led-strip

Salvaged LED Strip from old wide screen TV my grand son smashed. I have made a lamp from it; I can power it using a 12vdc 450ma power supply from somewhere.
I have few strips and wanted to make more.
My problem
I can light the strip using the 12vdc 450ma but not a 12vdc 2amp.? Only the 12vdc 450ma works?

Anyone know why and what other power supply will work?

Comment: Welcome! Impossible to tell without a schematic. Trace out yours. Does it have resistors or any ICs in series with the LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

If the LEDs don't have a way to limit the current in the form of a regulator circuit or series resistor then turning on a full 2 amps of current could burn out the string if the current was going directly into the LEDs. If there isn't any current limiting you'll need to limit it some way to 450 milliamp.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that the 12vdc 450ma supply is unregulated and the 12vdc 2amp is regulated.

Regulated supplies deliver the specified voltage whereas unregulated supplies tend to deliver slightly higher voltages until loaded by the amount specified (in this case 450ma).

If the led strip requires slightly more that 12 volt this would explain what you describe

You can measure both supplies with a voltmeter to see if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your 2A supply doesn't work or, more likely, is reverse polarity.